# Tabulator - Using ajaxURLGenerator property

Tags: tabulator

I have a back end Url that can be used like this:

https://url/?pageNumber=1&pageSize=20&search=test

"pageNumber" and "pageSize" works flawless with the "paginationDataSent" property.
The "search" parameter should be the one used as a filter but I can't figure it out how to do it since tabulator build the url like this:

https://url/?pageNumber=1&pageSize=20&search%5B0%5D%5Bfield%5D=term_name&search%5B0%5D%5Btype%5D=like&search%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=test

I know that I can change ajaxURLGenerator to make it work like I want but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it, it is pretty straight forwarded actually.
Here's the code if anyone encounters this same question:

If you are going to use more parameters, just add them with more conditions.

```
ajaxURLGenerator: function (url, config, params) {
            if (params.search[0] !== undefined)
                return url + "?pageNumber=" + params.pageNumber + "&pageSize=" + params.pageSize + "&search=" + params.search[0].value
            else
                return url + "?pageNumber=" + params.pageNumber + "&pageSize=" + params.pageSize
        },
```